# Heroku Precompiled Assets Failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, mongoid

I am having difficulties troubleshooting the following and figuring out why my assets are failing to precompile at slug compilation... the odd thing is, is that the assets compile fine at runtime when I check the live logs... any ideas? Is it trying to connect to the database?

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.1.4/lib/mongoid/sessions/mongo_uri.rb:49:in `initialize'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.1.4/lib/mongoid/sessions/factory.rb:104:in `new'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.1.4/lib/mongoid/sessions/factory.rb:104:in `parse'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.1.4/lib/mongoid/sessions/factory.rb:62:in `create_session'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.1.4/lib/mongoid/sessions/factory.rb:43:in `default'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.1.4/lib/mongoid/sessions.rb:109:in `default'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.1.4/lib/mongoid.rb:129:in `default_session'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.1.4/lib/mongoid/railtie.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `execute_hook'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
   /tmp/build_27348f41-abb7-46f0-a7ac-6f66bf0feff7/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
   Tasks: TOP => environment
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had just added Unicorn, I added the following to my application.rb in config and was able to precompile:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Answer (score 7):

Check whether your asset precompile requires access to ENV variables during when its run. Its hard to tell from your stack trace, but this might be a good resource to check out: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Essentially, you can enable the user-env-compile labs feature on heroku to give your app instance access to ENV vars during your precompile.

```
 heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp
```

more information about that here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile

Comment: Thanks derek, I tried pre-compiling locally `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile'` and when i run a trace I got the following error: `** Execute environment
rake aborted!
undefined method ``match' for nil:NilClass
/.../.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/mongoid-3.1.4/lib/mongoid/sessions/mongo_uri.rb:49:in ``initialize'` I installed the suggested add-on but I still get the same output...

Comment: strange, this thread also seems to point to the fact that it is related to the ENV vars http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775844/unicorn-triggers-mongoid-error-during-assets-precompile

Comment: is there a MONGOLAB_URI (or equivalent uri that it is trying to parse) that is set? Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492337/mongoid-fails-on-ruby-1-9-3

Comment: @derkyau Thanks, I had just added Unicorn so I added `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false' to my application.rb in config and I was able to precompile.

Comment: @Elliott I had the same error. Your solution works great.  Please post as an answer and mark as correct if it's the correct answer.  This is about signal vs. noise, not pride vs. humility.

Comment: As mentioned in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775844/unicorn-triggers-mongoid-error-during-assets-precompile adding `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile=false` will work with Rails 3 but not for Rails 4 apps.