# Unable to Push Rails App to Heroku - Issue Precompiling Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I'm pretty new to both Ruby and Rails, so thank you for taking the time to read my question.

My issue is that I'm unable to push a Rails app to Heroku. When I try, I get the following message.

---

```
> C:\RailsNew\mcl101>git push heroku master
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 353 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Warning:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at
 all.
       http[ed: removed link to to insufficient rep]...
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle -
-binstubs vendor/bundle/bin
       Fetching gem metadata from [ed: removed link due to insufficient rep]...........
       Fetching gem metadata from [ed: removed link due to insufficient rep]...
       Resolving dependencies...
       Using rake (10.1.1)
       Using i18n (0.6.9)
       Using multi_json (1.8.2)
       Using activesupport (3.2.14)
       Using builder (3.0.4)
       Using activemodel (3.2.14)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using journey (1.0.4)
       Using rack (1.4.5)
       Using rack-cache (1.2)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Using hike (1.2.3)
       Using tilt (1.4.1)
       Using sprockets (2.2.2)
       Using actionpack (3.2.14)
       Using mime-types (1.25.1)
       Using polyglot (0.3.3)
       Using treetop (1.4.15)
       Using mail (2.5.4)
       Using actionmailer (3.2.14)
       Using arel (3.0.3)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
       Using activerecord (3.2.14)
       Using activeresource (3.2.14)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
       Using execjs (2.0.2)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
       Using json (1.8.1)
       Using rdoc (3.12.2)
       Using thor (0.18.1)
       Using railties (3.2.14)
       Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Using jquery-rails (2.0.2)
       Using pg (0.12.2)
       Using rails (3.2.14)
       Using rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
       Using rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
       Using rails_12factor (0.0.2)
       Using sass (3.2.13)
       Using sass-rails (3.2.5)
       Using uglifier (1.2.3)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Bundle completed (6.76s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
       Compiled jquery.js  (3ms)  (pid 700)
       Compiled jquery_ujs.js  (0ms)  (pid 700)
       Compiled static_pages.js  (0ms)  (pid 700)
       Compiled application.js  (15ms)  (pid 700)
       rake aborted!
       Unexpected character '#' (line: 9783, col: 1, pos: 268384)
       Error
       at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20140102-700-pswwm7.js:497:22)
       at js_error (/tmp/execjs20140102-700-pswwm7.js:505:15)
       at parse_error (/tmp/execjs20140102-700-pswwm7.js:597:17)
       at Object.next_token [as input] (/tmp/execjs20140102-700-pswwm7.js:839:17
)
       at next (/tmp/execjs20140102-700-pswwm7.js:943:37)
       at Object.semicolon [as 1] (/tmp/execjs20140102-700-pswwm7.js:986:38)
       at prog1 (/tmp/execjs20140102-700-pswwm7.js:1530:28)
       at simple_statement (/tmp/execjs20140102-700-pswwm7.js:1123:35)
       at /tmp/execjs20140102-700-pswwm7.js:1039:40
       at /tmp/execjs20140102-700-pswwm7.js:1513:32
       (in /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/app/assets/javascript
s/application.js)/tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/r
uby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:68:in `extract_result
'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:28:in `block in exec'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:41:in `compile_to_tempfile'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:27:in `exec'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/uglifier-1.2.3/lib/uglifier.rb:101:in `compile'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:74:in `compress'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:265:in `block in js_compressor=
'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `call'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `evaluate'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:193:in `block in evaluate'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:190:in `each'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:190:in `evaluate'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:26:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `new'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:19:in `block in compile'

       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:219:in `block in each_logical_path'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:206:in `block (2 levels) in each_file
'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each_entry'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:204:in `block in each_file'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each_file'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:217:in `each_logical_path'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top
 (required)>'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top
 (required)>'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_ta
sk'
       /tmp/build_364edaac-c703-4702-b865-9a776254c355/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top
 (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app


To git@heroku.com:sheltered-brushlands-4377.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:sheltered-brushlands-4377.git
```

Doing a bit of research on here, and by looking at the error, it seemed that the problem was something to do with precompiling of assets.

So I added the following code to ../config/application.rb:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

This seemed to work, as I was now able to push my app to Heroku. But now when I try to visit the site, I get an application error, which says that my app cannot be served. So I ran the logs:

```
C:\RailsNew\mcl101>heroku logs
2014-01-02T13:31:50.786546+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-02T13:31:50.786546+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'

2014-01-02T13:31:52.037593+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-01-02T13:31:52.056076+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2014-01-02T15:16:11.842881+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/ host=sheltered-brushlands-4377.herokuapp.com fwd="204.15
2.207.170" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-02T15:30:24.407393+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=sheltered-brushlands-4377.herokuapp.com
fwd="204.152.207.170" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-02T15:30:21.620843+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/ host=sheltered-brushlands-4377.herokuapp.com fwd="204.15
2.207.170" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-02T15:30:25.174076+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=sheltered-brushlands-4377.herokuapp.com
fwd="204.152.207.170" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-02T15:36:06+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-01-02T15:36:56.553763+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy ba635d7 by j.knoll621@gmail
.com
2014-01-02T15:36:56.583136+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by j.knoll621@g
mail.com
2014-01-02T15:36:56+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-01-02T15:36:56.885265+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2014-01-02T15:37:00.326555+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
undle exec rails server -p 48960`
2014-01-02T15:37:04.734154+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2014-01-02T15:37:04.734201+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-02T15:37:04.734257+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'

2014-01-02T15:37:04.734035+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/application.rb:4:in `<t
op (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (Na
meError)
2014-01-02T15:37:04.734035+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
2014-01-02T15:37:04.734154+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-01-02T15:37:04.734257+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2014-01-02T15:37:06.097451+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-01-02T15:37:09.142098+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
undle exec rails server -p 30034`
2014-01-02T15:37:11.602040+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2014-01-02T15:37:11.602040+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/application.rb:4:in `<t
op (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (Na
meError)
2014-01-02T15:37:11.602040+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-01-02T15:37:11.602040+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
2014-01-02T15:37:11.602040+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'

2014-01-02T15:37:11.602040+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-02T15:37:11.602040+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2014-01-02T15:37:12.990230+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-01-02T15:37:13.004552+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2014-01-02T15:37:06.115394+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2014-01-02T15:37:06.116811+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2014-01-02T15:48:01.013531+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/ host=sheltered-brushlands-4377.herokuapp.com fwd="204.15
2.207.170" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-02T15:48:08.089103+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=sheltered-brushlands-4377.herokuapp.com
fwd="204.152.207.170" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-02T16:34:13.326232+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/ host=sheltered-brushlands-4377.herokuapp.com fwd="204.15
2.207.170" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-02T16:34:56.645390+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bun
dle exec rake db:migrate` by j.knoll621@gmail.com
2014-01-02T16:35:01.839866+00:00 heroku[run.5825]: Awaiting client
2014-01-02T16:35:01.838431+00:00 heroku[run.5825]: State changed from starting t
o up
2014-01-02T16:35:01.918075+00:00 heroku[run.5825]: Starting process with command
 `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2014-01-02T16:35:05.282643+00:00 heroku[run.5825]: Process exited with status 1
2014-01-02T16:35:05.296168+00:00 heroku[run.5825]: State changed from up to comp
lete
2014-01-02T16:37:36.671768+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bun
dle exec rake db:migrate --trade` by j.knoll621@gmail.com
2014-01-02T16:37:40.391686+00:00 heroku[run.3032]: Awaiting client
2014-01-02T16:37:40.434212+00:00 heroku[run.3032]: State changed from starting t
o up
2014-01-02T16:37:53.327294+00:00 heroku[run.1381]: State changed from starting t
o up
2014-01-02T16:37:53.497702+00:00 heroku[run.1381]: Awaiting client
2014-01-02T16:37:56.108478+00:00 heroku[run.1381]: Starting process with command
 `bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace`
2014-01-02T16:37:58.606115+00:00 heroku[run.1381]: State changed from up to comp
lete
2014-01-02T16:37:58.596113+00:00 heroku[run.1381]: Process exited with status 1
2014-01-02T16:37:49.190853+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bun
dle exec rake db:migrate --trace` by j.knoll621@gmail.com
2014-01-02T16:38:10.394260+00:00 heroku[run.3032]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> F
ailed to attach to process
2014-01-02T16:38:11.687514+00:00 heroku[run.3032]: Process exited with status 12
8
2014-01-02T16:38:11.699991+00:00 heroku[run.3032]: State changed from up to comp
lete
2014-01-02T16:42:23.044171+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bun
dle exec rake db:migrate --trace` by j.knoll621@gmail.com
2014-01-02T16:42:28.740441+00:00 heroku[run.5363]: Awaiting client
2014-01-02T16:42:28.791316+00:00 heroku[run.5363]: Starting process with command
 `bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace`
2014-01-02T16:42:28.887756+00:00 heroku[run.5363]: State changed from starting t
o up
2014-01-02T16:42:31.377482+00:00 heroku[run.5363]: State changed from up to comp
lete
2014-01-02T16:42:31.375346+00:00 heroku[run.5363]: Process exited with status 1
2014-01-02T16:49:47+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-01-02T16:50:05+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed
 to compile Ruby app
2014-01-02T16:52:07.680249+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2014-01-02T16:52:12.874719+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
undle exec rails server -p 25475`
2014-01-02T16:52:16.269490+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/application.rb:4:in `<t
op (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (Na
meError)
2014-01-02T16:52:16.269490+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
2014-01-02T16:52:16.269490+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-01-02T16:52:16.269490+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2014-01-02T16:52:16.269490+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-02T16:52:16.269490+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'

2014-01-02T16:52:16.269490+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2014-01-02T16:52:17.887964+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-01-02T16:52:17.933750+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2014-01-02T17:15:43+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-01-02T17:16:16.064916+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy a366609 by j.knoll621@gmail
.com
2014-01-02T17:16:16.719947+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by j.knoll621@g
mail.com
2014-01-02T17:16:16+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-01-02T17:16:21.356805+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
undle exec rails server -p 6069`
2014-01-02T17:16:23.613703+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/application.rb:4:in `<t
op (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (Na
meError)
2014-01-02T17:16:23.613703+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2014-01-02T17:16:23.613703+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'

2014-01-02T17:16:23.613703+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2014-01-02T17:16:23.613703+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
2014-01-02T17:16:23.613703+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-01-02T17:16:23.613703+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-02T17:16:24.919650+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-01-02T17:16:24.935954+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2014-01-02T17:16:24.935066+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2014-01-02T17:16:28.179246+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
undle exec rails server -p 3013`
2014-01-02T17:16:30.438557+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-01-02T17:16:30.438773+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-02T17:16:30.438878+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'

2014-01-02T17:16:30.438235+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/application.rb:4:in `<t
op (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (Na
meError)
2014-01-02T17:16:30.438441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
2014-01-02T17:16:30.438665+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2014-01-02T17:16:30.438986+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2014-01-02T17:16:31.716131+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-01-02T17:16:31.727940+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2014-01-02T17:16:33.515811+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/ host=sheltered-brushlands-4377.herokuapp.com fwd="204.15
2.207.170" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-02T17:16:40.637813+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=sheltered-brushlands-4377.herokuapp.com
fwd="204.152.207.170" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Still not sure what the issue is. Here is rake db:migrate --trace as well

```
C:\RailsNew\mcl101>heroku run rake db:migrate --trace
Running `rake db:migrate --trace` attached to terminal... up, run.1381
rake aborted!
undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
/app/config/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/app/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/app/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:637:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `s
tandard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

Please let me know if you see anything in that I'm doing completely wrong. Any feedback or assistance would be much appreciated. I apologize if this question has been answered on here before. I found a few similar questions, but nothing that could help me, and I've been puzzling over this for the better part of a week.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Refer to this question/answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972514/heroku-precompiled-assets-failed/18972698#18972698

Comment: Does your app run normally on localhost, it seems there is something wrong with your migrations. I'm saying this because of this line in the output => rake aborted!
       Unexpected character '#' (line: 9783, col: 1, pos: 268384)
       Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does your app run normally on localhost, it seems there is something
>   wrong with your migrations. I'm saying this because of this line in
>   the output => rake aborted! Unexpected character '#' (line: 9783, col:
>   1, pos: 268384) Error –  Tom Hagen Jan 3 at 10:37

Thanks Tom. Your comment pointed me in the right direction and I figured out the problem. Closing the topic as there are already similar questions.